# LB-Link (Model No=WN155A) Driver

Tags: drivers, wireless

I'm new to Ubuntu. I have bought a new USB Wi-Fi adapter (LB-Link- WN155A) and I need to install the driver from CD that came with it,  but I can't find any executable files.

I tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/842007/how-to-install-linux-driver-for-a-lb-link-wireless-usb-adapter but this did not help.

I uploaded the [contents of the CD to Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-JmvL9zDs3JSHhoQXkzZnRpYjA).

The result of `lsusb`:

[image]

The result of `uname -r`:

> ```
> 3.19.0-74-generic
> ```

Comment: The files you have are circa-2013 and it is doubtful that they will compile properly on any recent Ubuntu version. Please edit your question to add the result of: `lsusb` and also: `uname -r` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks (@chili555) i will edit my qeustion but please tell me how to compile these files i tried alot but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will outline the usual process to compile the files. This may or may not compile on your 3.19-xx kernel. If not, post the errors and I will propose another solution.

First, remove the device. Next, in the terminal, with a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Next, navigate to the location of the Makefile; in my case:

```
cd ~/Downloads/DPA_MT7601U_LinuxAP_3.0.0.1_20130802/DPA_MT7601U_LinuxAP_3.0.0.1_20130802
```

Now let's try a trial compilation:

```
make
```

If there are errors, please post them here and we'll attempt to fix them. If there are no errors (warnings may be OK), then install:

```
sudo make install
```

Insert the device. Is your wireless now working?

**EDIT**: Since we know now that the driver files included with your device will *not* compile in kernel version 3.19-xx, please try:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/art567/mt7601usta.git
cd mt7601/src
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

Please post any errors as before.

You have compiled the driver for your current kernel version only. When Update Manager offers a later kernel version, known as linux-image, after the requested reboot, recompile:

```
cd mt7601/src
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: when i execute make command i faced the following problem  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-JmvL9zDs3JRXRBZ1RuR29PWmM

Comment: That's what we call at our house, a trainwreck. You were warned earlier that, "...it is doubtful that they will compile properly on any recent Ubuntu version." I shall edit my answer to propose a better solution.

Comment: thanks alot @chili555 that worked for me......you're great

Comment: Please take note of my edit above.

Comment: it worked as you describe without any problem